# webpack error: [webpack-cli] Error: Conflict: Multiple chunks emit assets to the same filename styles/styles.ab6b56e41b61fd0ef6a6.css

Tags: javascript, webpack, railway

I'm getting a webpack error when I try to deploy a project to Railway. My styles file is in styles>index.scss.
Would appreciate any suggestions as to how to fix, thanks in advance.

sample code:

```
#13 12.67 [webpack-cli] Error: Conflict: Multiple chunks emit assets to the same filename styles/styles.ab6b56e41b61fd0ef6a6.css (chunks 143 and 532)
#13 12.67     at /app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:4617:12
#13 12.67     at /app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Cache.js:93:5
#13 12.67     at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
#13 12.67     at Cache.get (/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Cache.js:75:18)
#13 12.67     at ItemCacheFacade.get (/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/CacheFacade.js:111:15)
#13 12.67     at /app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:4563:22
#13 12.67     at arrayEach (/app/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2405:9)
#13 12.67     at Object.each (/app/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2846:9)
#13 12.67     at /app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:4552:14
#13 12.67     at symbolIterator (/app/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:3482:9)
#13 12.67     at timesSync (/app/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2297:7)
#13 12.67     at Object.eachLimit (/app/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:3463:5)
#13 12.67     at Compilation.createChunkAssets `
```